# Updating the date column to 1900-01-01 of first row of every ID column

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse-analytics

There is a table with ID, Name, frmdate, todate, actvflg. It has got couple of records and mainly used for historization. Like with ID = 1 could be having multiple rows where only one will be active with actvflg='Y'. Let say in this case, there are 5 rows with ID=1, Now the challenge is I should update only first row of each ID where frmdate is the minimum of all the rows available grouped by ID.How to do this in **Synapse** as partitioning and few things are not applicable? Basically looking out for filter condition in subquery

Following is the code that I have tried -

```
DECLARE @frm_ts DATETIME = CAST('1900-01-01' AS DATETIME)

Update dbo.table1
set frmdate = @frm_ts
WHERE frmdate IN 
(SELECT Min(frmdate) as frmdate FROM dbo.table1 Group by ID)
```

Comment: You need a _correlated subquery_, i.e. one that matches the ID.